How to exclude files in php buildback?
I am using Digitalocean's App Platform to deploy a PHP app.
App Platform recommends to use their PHP buildpack to deploy PHP apps.
It seems to utilize heroku-buildpack-php for this purpose.
Deploy works but how can i exclude some files to be copied to the deployed app.
For example the tests dir should not end up in the deploy.
I tried already to add a project.toml file with an exclude directive, but this did not work.
I know i can use Docker instead and have a .dockerignore in effect, but currently i am stucked to the Buildpack here.
